# Running model in custom Data Set(2 classes) error in testing phase (MXNet framework)

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, training-data, mxnet

i am running a model for my own data set(the project was implemented for training/testing with ImageNet) with 2 classes. I have made all the changes (in config files etc) but after training finishes(successfully), i get the following error when starting testing:

```
wrote gt roidb to ./data/cache/ImageNetVID_DET_val_gt_roidb.pkl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "experiments/dff_rfcn/dff_rfcn_end2end_train_test.py", line 20, in <module>
    test.main()
  File "experiments/dff_rfcn/../../dff_rfcn/test.py", line 53, in main
    args.vis, args.ignore_cache, args.shuffle, config.TEST.HAS_RPN, config.dataset.proposal, args.thresh, logger=logger, output_path=final_output_path)
  File "experiments/dff_rfcn/../../dff_rfcn/function/test_rcnn.py", line 68, in test_rcnn
    roidbs_seg_lens[gpu_id] += x['frame_seg_len']
KeyError: 'frame_seg_len'
```

I cleaned the cache file before running. As i have read in previous topics, this might be an issue of previous datasets .pkl files in cache. What may have caused this error? I also want to mention that i changed .txt filenames that feed the neural network(if this is important), and that training finishes well.
This is my first time running a project in Deep Learning so please show some understanding.

Comment: Is this testing using a saved model?

Comment: Looks like this question is specific to the [FGFA](https://github.com/msracver/Flow-Guided-Feature-Aggregation) implementation. Filing an [issue](https://github.com/msracver/Flow-Guided-Feature-Aggregation/issues) in that repo might be the best way to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MXNet typically uses methods other than `pickle` directly for serialization of the model architecture and trained weights.

With Gluon API, you can save weights of the model to a file (i.e. Block) with [`.save_params()`](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/gluon/gluon.html?highlight=save_par#mxnet.gluon.Block.save_params) and then load the weights from a file with [`.load_params()`](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/gluon/gluon.html?highlight=load_params#mxnet.gluon.Block.load_params). You 'save' the model architecture by keeping the code used to define the model. See and example of this [here](http://gluon.mxnet.io/chapter03_deep-neural-networks/serialization.html).

With Module API, you can create checkpoints at the end of each epoch which will save the symbol (i.e. model architecture) and the parameters (i.e. model weights). See [here](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/tutorials/basic/module.html).

```
checkpoint = mx.callback.do_checkpoint(model_prefix)
mod = mx.mod.Module(symbol=net)
mod.fit(train_iter, num_epoch=5, epoch_end_callback=checkpoint)
```

You can then load the model of a given checkpoint (e.g. 42 in this example)

```
sym, arg_params, aux_params = mx.model.load_checkpoint(model_prefix, 42)
mod.set_params(arg_params, aux_params)
```